# GeneratedAssetSymbols.swift generated by cocoapods'pod how to used in other pod

Tags: catalog, xcode15

GeneratedAssetSymbols.swift generated by cocoapods'pod how to used in other pod？In Xcode 15 New function。

image asset in APod, **iconA**
how to use **iconA** in BPod

APod generate Imagesource enum to GeneratedAssetSymbols.swift.
BPod also generate Imagesource enum to GeneratedAssetSymbols.swift.

But these GeneratedAssetSymbols.swift files is not shared, how to share?

APod generate Imagesource enum to GeneratedAssetSymbols.swift.
BPod also generate Imagesource enum to GeneratedAssetSymbols.swift.

But these GeneratedAssetSymbols.swift files is not shared, how to share?

Comment: how do you make the generator working for private pod? build in it's own example project? does it work in host project dev pod mode?